# Learning Javascript vs. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the Wrox.Beginning.JavaScript.3rd.Edition and wanted to start learning it from scratch, then my boss came along and said that why bother, learn jQuery.
Can I understand jQuery and work with it although I am a newbie and have limited knowledge in ASP.net, vb.net, some C#, and basic HTML?!

Comment: Your boss is a little confused. JQuery is just a Javascript library/API. You should have a foundation in Javascript and then learn JQuery. Although, you can typically get just a basic Javascript understanding and then start using JQuery. I do recommend removing the "machine learning" tag is that is not really relevant here.

Comment: I disagree with the masses on this. jQuery *is* javascript, but it also simplifies many aspects of javascript programming, such as DOM traversal and DOM manipulation, as well as providing a plugin architecture.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

jQuery *is* javascript. I think you're on the right path.  Learn javascript well and you'll be able to make better use of jQuery.

Comment: Not to mention that someday you may be required to use a framework or library apart from jQuery, so a solid foundation in Javascript is very important. (Learn both, though. Don't shelve one for the other).

Comment: You might also want to consider moving jobs if you're stuck with the sort of boss who'll tell you to learn things without actually knowing what they are :( Best of luck.

Comment: I learned javascript first, and later discovered the awesomeness that is jquery. I don't regret a minute spent reading O'Reilly, javascript, The definitive guide. Also, ur boss might feel pressure from above to produce code quickly be it good or not so try a diplomatic approach and you'll get much further if you can help him make an argument to his superiors for learning and doing things in a way that benefits everyone.

Answer (score 8):

So what's your question? JQuery is a *framework* built on the top of a *language* JavaScript. To use JQuery confidently, you should get familiar with JavaScript. JQuery contains a bunch of useful patterns and utils that mask the incompatibilities of the browsers. Using a JavaScript framework make sense as it allows you to focus on your problem instead of the problem of the JavaScript implementations of the browsers.

For further details on JavaScript frameworks, see SO question [»Which Javascript framework (jQuery vs Dojo vs … )?«](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs). For learning JavaScript, [learn the good parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/).

Answer (score 5):

if all your manager is asking from you is to show and hide some elements, or fade in and out a couple of images, or request some data via ajax and display it then learning jquery and its api is perhaps all that you need.

but if you  (or your manager) are concerned about performance, maintainability, code reuse and generally understanding what the *ell is going on 'back there' then learning the language itself is a safe bet.

I would suggest grabbing a copy of [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996), which will give you a general understanding of what it is and how to use it, and much more. While you are at it, I also suggest John Resig's Pro Javascript techniques. This guy really knows his javascript inside-out (works for mozilla, author of jQuery, amongst others).

As for jQuery, you don't really need to buy a book. Just browse through the API and have a look at its source code. Perhaps you won't understand much, but there are some cool stuff going on that will make you think.

Answer (score 4):

It is entirely possible to learn jQuery without learning every bit of javascript first. However, to be productive and and extend the functionality of plugins etc you will need to know javascript.

I would suggest that you do a bit of both. Continue learning Javascript but when you want to implement functionality make use of the jQuery library.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the statement is akin to you reading a C#/VB.Net book and having your boss say "Don't bother, just learn ASP.Net".  You really don't get much from the latter without the former.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is made from javascript. :)

It would be a **very good idea** to read the source-code of jQuery to enhance your overall understanding of javascript...

Definitely learn both at the same time :)
***Good luck and have fun.***

Answer (score 2):

JQuery provides a good layer of abstraction for interacting with DOM elements. You can do a lot of interesting things with it quickly and easily. But there are probably many things that JQuery won't do for you. You'll need to use regular JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery removes the need for many bad Javascript habits.
However, you will frequently need to know more than just jQuery to get non-trivial work done.

You'll need to learn both, but try to pick up habits based on jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your boss is trying to save you some time learning the basics of Javascript and start you off learning jQuery right away but I think this would be a bad idea.

Understanding the basics of javascript is key to using jQuery successfully. jQuery provides shortcuts and solutions to problems (cross browser problems etc) but it is not a language unto it's self.

My advice, learn javascript, learn about handling events in different browsers, inserting in to the DOM and then start using jQuery. You will appreciate it a lot more and be a better coder for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have an understanding of C#, you'll have a head start learning Javascript and it shouldn't be too hard to pick up. I'd stick with that Javascript book though, since you need to know Javascript to use jQuery. Once you are comfortable with Javascript, move on to learning jQuery. The jQuery docs are VERY helpful and can answer almost any question you have.

Good luck with learning it, it'll be worth it.

[jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

what are U doing? - ofcourse pure JavaScript is better =)

Answer (score 0):

Libraries will alwas contain nonessential complexity, but they can save some headaches if they're not too bloated or already present on the end users' systems.  Best use would be to learn javascript while using jquery, and then slowly remove the crutch of using jquery.  While it's powerful, it does add significant overhead, nonessential complexity, and potential opportunities for abuse, just like flash.  There are no silver bullets.